# MySQL/Python - Rechazar consultas si la base de datos, tabla y columna no se escriben dentro de ` (acento grave/backtick)

Tags: python, python-3.x, mysqldb

Quisiera saber si hay una forma en la que puedo crear restricciones a la hora de ejecutar una consulta.
Lo que esperaría es que al tener una consulta como la siguiente:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `database`.`table` WHERE `column` = 1; -- Notese los ` (acento grave/backtick)
```

Se ejecute sin problemas.

**Pero** cuando la consulta sea como la siguiente:

```sql
SELECT column FROM database.table WHERE other_column = "N/A"; -- Notese la falta de ` (acento grave/backtick)
```

**Se impida la ejecución del SQL.**

Mi conexión se realiza de la siguiente forma:

```py
import MySQLdb
from sshtunel import SSHTunerForwarder

class ssh_mysql_exception(Exception):
    pass

class ssh_mysql(object):
    def __init__(self, dsn):
        if 'server_ip' not in dsn or \
           'server_user' not in dsn or \
           'server_pass' not in dsn or \
           'mysql_ip' not in dsn or \
           'mysql_user' not in dsn or \
           'mysql_pass' not in dsn: 
            raise ssh_mysql_exception("Malformed DSN Object")

        self.s_ip = dsn['server_ip']
        self.s_user = dsn['server_user']
        self.s_pass = dsn['server_pass']
        self.mys_ip = dsn['mysql_ip']
        self.mys_user = dsn['mysql_user']
        self.mys_pass = dsn['mysql_pass']

    def query(self, sql):
        with SSHTunnelForwarder(
            (self.s_ip, 22),
            ssh_password=self.s_pass,
            ssh_username=self.s_user,
            remote_bind_address=(self.mys_ip, 3306)
        ) as server:
            driver = MySQLdb.connect(
                host="127.0.0.1",
                port=server.local_bind_port,
                user=self.mys_user,
                passwd=self.mys_pass
            )

            cur = driver.cursor()
            try:
                cur.execute(sql)
                return cur, cur.rowcount
            except Exception as e:
                server.close()
                return str(e)
```

La clase recibe un objeto que tiene las *keys* correspondientes (server_ip, mysql_ip, etc) para que la conexión sea exitosa.

Hay alguna forma de indicarle la *˝regla˝* o *˝restricción˝* a SQL desde la conexión o debo encontrar una forma de hacerlo con Python?

Comment: Hola, ¿alguna razón especial para querer usar los backticks? Pregunto para conocer el contexto.

Comment: Para evitar bugs respecto a consultas y también formas de ataques SQL. También, luego agregaré *strip* a caracteres como "--" y ";". Es básicamente un SQL Builder, sólo que no pueden ejecutarse 2 consultas (SELECT blabla; SELECT other; SELECT ...), sólo una. Y si hay más de una, debería fallar debido al *strip* que te mencioné.

Comment: Ya veo. Entiendo entonces que vas a recibir una consulta SQL directamente desde el input de algún usuario.

Comment: Si señor. Por ello quisiera formar éstas reglas.